# Android-facebook chat client using xmpp in android

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, asmack

Am New to android, Now I am trying to develop a facebook chat client using asmack  , I am able to login using the following code ,
    // for creating and authorize the connection FBMessageListener is message listener class
      public String connect() throws XMPPException {

```
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222); // This is to avoid the keystore exception.
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
    config.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
    config.setTruststoreType("bks");

    connection = new XMPPConnection(config); 
    mFbml = new FBMessageListener(connection);

    try 
    {     
        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism( "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism.class);     

        connection.connect(); 

    } 
    catch (XMPPException e) 
    {     
        connection.disconnect();     
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    return connection.getConnectionID();
 }     
and for login 
connection.login(userName, password, FB_XMPP_HOST);  
 But the problem is the message is not sending . There is no error or exception in the logcat .That is why i am struggling !! This is my code to send the message..
ChatManager chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
// am able to get the userjid ..
 public void sendMessage() throws XMPPException {
    Chat chat = chatManager.createChat("userjid", mFbml);
    String text = "Testing client";
    Log.v(" Successsssssss===========", "Your Messge "+text+"has been sent");
    chat.sendMessage(text );
   }
In Logcat showing when sending the 
message //userjid mentioned above
<message id="f4zMl-13" to="userjid" type="chat"><body>TEstingggggggggg</body>   <thread>QwLOE5</thread></message>
Please help me to do the chatting.!!
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233702/1318048) solves your problem.

Comment: Hey Look [this Link][1] it will give u Help



[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395185/xmpp-facebook-not-send-message/11590238#11590238][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395185/xmpp-facebook-not-send-message/11590238#11590238
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395185/xmpp-facebook-not-send-message/11590238#11590238

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SMACK.JAR which has a XMPP client API's

[Smack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/)

you can find an XMPP Client For Android in this [link](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/)

Comment: Hi thank you for answering my question , But i have already tried the link , But that didn't worked for me.I think facebook chat is different!! If you have any working code please post it .thanks in advane

Answer (score 0):

First of all Edit your SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism class . Copy and paste this code .

```
package com.facebook.android;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.sasl.Sasl;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.Base64;

import android.util.Log;

public class SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism extends SASLMechanism {

    private static final String NAME              = "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";

    private String              apiKey            = "";
    private String              accessToken        = "";

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
        super(saslAuthentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new AuthMechanism(NAME, ""));
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String apiKey, String host, String accessToken) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        if (apiKey == null || accessToken == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameters");
        }

        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.hostname = host;

        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, this);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, CallbackHandler cbh) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        String[] mechanisms = { "DIGEST-MD5" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, cbh);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void challengeReceived(String challenge) throws IOException {
        byte[] response = null;

        if (challenge != null) {
            String decodedChallenge = new String(Base64.decode(challenge));
            Map<String, String> parameters = getQueryMap(decodedChallenge);

            String version = "1.0";
            String nonce = parameters.get("nonce");
            String method = parameters.get("method");

            String composedResponse =
                "method=" + URLEncoder.encode(method, "utf-8") +
                        "&nonce=" + URLEncoder.encode(nonce, "utf-8") +
                        "&access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(accessToken, "utf-8") +
                        "&api_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8") +
                        "&call_id=0" +
                        "&v=" + URLEncoder.encode(version, "utf-8");
            response = composedResponse.getBytes();
        }

        String authenticationText = "";

        if (response != null) {
            authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(response);
        }

        // Send the authentication to the server
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new Response(authenticationText));
    }

    private Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] params = query.split("\\&");

        for (String param : params) {
            String[] fields = param.split("=", 2);
            map.put(fields[0], (fields.length > 1 ? fields[1] : null));
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

Then use this method in your activity class to login to facebook .

```
private void testLogin(){
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
        xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM",SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAppId());
        Log.i("XMPPClient",
                "Access token to " + mFacebook.getAccessToken());
        try {
            xmpp.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Connected to " + xmpp.getHost());

        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Unable to " + xmpp.getHost());

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            xmpp.login(PreferenceConnector.APP_ID, mFacebook.getAccessToken());
            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    " its logined ");


        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```