# xmpp facebook not send message

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp

There is one Android Open Source Project available : Beem Project and For connecting Facebook chat you can used following guidelines.

Steps for implementing Facebook chat API in Android:

First we have to implement MemorizingTrustManager Library project in existing project.

> => For that you have to copy following three files in existing project
>
> MemorizingTrustManager/src/de/duenndns/ssl/MTMDecision.java
>   MemorizingTrustManager/src/de/duenndns/ssl/MemorizingActivity.java
>   MemorizingTrustManager/src/de/duenndns/ssl/MemorizingTrustManager.java
>   => And add following values in values/string.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="mtm_accept_cert">Accept Unknown Certificate?</string>
    <string name="mtm_decision_always">Always</string>
    <string name="mtm_decision_once">Once</string>
    <string name="mtm_decision_abort">Abort</string>
    <string name="mtm_notification">Certificate Verification</string>
</resources>
```

Second step, Instead of using SASLAuthentication such as X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM, You can used following code to connect with Facebook and login using your Facebook Jabber ID (username@chat.facebook.com)

```
    public void connectToFb() throws XMPPException {

ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
config.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
config.setTruststoreType("bks");
config.setSendPresence(false);
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, MemorizingTrustManager.getInstanceList(this), new java.security.SecureRandom());
    config.setCustomSSLContext(sc);
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    Log.w("TAG", "Unable to use MemorizingTrustManager", e);
}
XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
try {
    xmpp.connect();
    xmpp.login("facebookusername", "****"); // Here you have to used only facebookusername from facebookusername@chat.facebook.com
    Roster roster = xmpp.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    System.out.println("Connected!");
    System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
    // shows first time onliners---->
    String temp[] = new String[50];
    int i = 0;
    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
        String user = entry.getUser();
        Log.i("TAG", user);
    }
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    xmpp.disconnect();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

above example run but not send message.How can I send the message?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will Use for You.

```
        String msg = edtMsg.getText().toString().trim(); 
    edtMsg.setText("");

    if(!msg.equals("")){
        Message msgObj = new Message("xxx@chat.facebook.com", Message.Type.chat);
        msgObj.setBody(msg);
        connection.sendPacket(msgObj);
    }
```

Comment: Store all the Message in ArrayList ,  and setAdapter every time on UI,

Comment: how i can add stamp attribute with message tag? as i need to send stamp when sending message and display sending time when it display on device.

Comment: @GautamVasoya I am facing problem in sending msg over xmpp, can you come over this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68853/trying-to-learn) to help in solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to set Connection after login successfully.

/**
     * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is establised with the XMPP
     * server
     * 
     * @param connection
     */

```
public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {

        this.connection = connection;
        if (connection != null) {
            // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                                .getFrom());
                        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Got text [" + message.getBody()
                                + "] from [" + fromName + "]");
                        messages.add(fromName + ":");
                        messages.add(message.getBody());
                        // Add the incoming message to the list view
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                setListAdapter();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        }
    }



private void setListAdapter() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.multi_line_list_item, messages);
        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: connection succesfully.incoming message list succesfully but not send message.How can I send the message?  
example:  Message msg = new Message("xxxxx", Message.Type.chat);
            msg.setBody("request");
            connection.sendPacket(msg);
            setConnection(connection); is not working

Comment: Check this link, may be it is useful for us: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/                               http://samse.tistory.com/entry/Android-Smack-example

Comment: I looked but could not send message :(

Comment: @kalpana I am facing problem in sending msg over xmpp, can you come over this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68853/trying-to-learn) to help in solving the problem